# Flutter error Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac' and config ':app:debugCompileClasspath'

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, flutter-doctor

I don't know anymore how to handle this issue. There is no good documentation regarding this issue.

I've tried upgrading gradle to the latest version as well as upgrading build tools and so on. Some people even asked me to run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` and I did it, it didn't work.

The error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve com.google.zxing:core:{strictly 3.3.0}.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Cannot find a version of 'com.google.zxing:core' that satisfies the version constraints: 
           Dependency path 'android:app:unspecified' --> 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:8.2.0' --> 'com.facebook.android:facebook-common:8.2.0' --> 'com.google.zxing:core:3.3.3'
           Constraint path 'android:app:unspecified' --> 'com.google.zxing:core:{strictly 3.3.0}' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 3.3.0

   > Could not resolve com.google.zxing:core:3.3.3.
     Required by:
         project :app > com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:8.2.0 > com.facebook.android:facebook-common:8.2.0
      > Cannot find a version of 'com.google.zxing:core' that satisfies the version constraints: 
           Dependency path 'android:app:unspecified' --> 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:8.2.0' --> 'com.facebook.android:facebook-common:8.2.0' --> 'com.google.zxing:core:3.3.3'
           Constraint path 'android:app:unspecified' --> 'com.google.zxing:core:{strictly 3.3.0}' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 3.3.0
```

What Flutter Doctor says about me

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.4, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.1348], locale en-US)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
[!] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)
    X Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    X Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
    X Unable to determine bundled Java version.
[√] VS Code (version 1.63.0)
[√] Connected device (1 available)
```

P.S. I've installed Flutter and Dart plugins. No idea why it's still listed as not installed. Have restarted my PC for several times as well. I also have no idea why it can't determine bundle Java version.

Comment: install git 
https://git-scm.com/downloads

flutter gives error sometime if git is not installed

Comment: installing git is a must. This is not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your android SDK. Note your SDK path (`SDK_path`) and then use it for config.
Here is the command:

```
flutter config --android-studio-dir="SDK_path"
```

Then run flutter doctor again.

Comment: still not working